# How to make pagination elasticsearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am new with elasticsearch.

I try to make real app. I am using elasticsearch-php
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php

I don't know to make pagination.

my code :

```
<?php
require_once 'app/init.php';

if(isset ($_GET['q'])) {

  $q = $_GET['q'];

  $query = $es->search([
    'index' => 'user',
    'type' => 'profile',
    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        'bool' => [
          'should' => [
            'match' => ['bio' => $q]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
  ]);
  if ($query['hits']['total'] >=1) {
    $results= $query['hits']['hits'];
  }

}

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Search | ES</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="index.php" method="get" autocomplete="off">
      <label for="">
          Search
          <input type="text" name="q">
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>
    <?php
      if (isset($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $r) {
      ?>
          <div class="result">
            <?php echo $r['_source']['bio']; ?>
          </div>
     <?php
        }
      }
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

and how to make pagination like this :

[View image Pagination like github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUEJh.png)

Answer (score 5):

You need two things here, total number of pages and way to navigate from one page to other.
When you query elassticsearch with simple `Query->filter->bool`

It returns hits in the response JSON which is the total number of results. Divide them with the number of results you want to show on the App, you will get pages.

Use from and size property in your PHP-elasticsearch request object and change keep changing from on navigating between the pages. Example query(considering page 3 and page size 10)

```
{
    "from": 20,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "FIELD": {
                            "value": "VALUE"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```